# ¿Cómo aplicar SweetAlert2?

Tags: javascript, sweetalert2

me gustaria saber como aplicar sweetalert2 en uno de los botones que he creado que da las preguntas correctas e incorrectas de un quiz con javascript... ¿Podrían decirme?:

```js
function mostrarResultado() {
  const respuestas = contenedor.querySelectorAll(".respuestas");
  let respuestasCorrectas = 0;

  preguntas.forEach((preguntaActual, numerodePregunta) => {
    const todaslasRespuestas = respuestas[numerodePregunta];
    const checkboxRespuestas = `input[name='${numerodePregunta}']:checked`;
    const respuestaElegida = (todaslasRespuestas.querySelector(checkboxRespuestas) || {}).value;

    if (respuestaElegida === preguntaActual.respuestaCorrecta) {
      respuestasCorrectas++;

      respuestas[numerodePregunta].style.color = `blue`;

    } else {
      respuestas[numerodePregunta].style.color = `red`;
    }
  })

  resultadoQuiz.innerHTML = 'Usted acerto' + respuestasCorrectas + 'pregunta de un total de' + preguntas.length

}

botonRespuesta.addEventListener('click', mostrarResultado);
```

```html
<div class="button">
  <button id="boton" class="button">¡Mostrar Resultado!</button>
</div>
```

Comment: sucede que botonrespuesta no ha sido definido. saludos.

Comment: ¿Para definirlo cómo sería?.

Comment: generalmente mediante `var botonRespuesta` o `let botonRespuesta`, la inicializacion depende de la combinacion de frameworks que uses

Answer (score 0):

La documentacion de sweetAlert2 es muy clara la verdad, https://sweetalert2.github.io/

la manera mas sencilla seria desde su CDN `<script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/sweetalert2@11"></script>`

colocando esa CDN en el archivo más alto de tu proyecto como algun index.html o algún otro que tenga como raíz, podría empezar a utilizar los distintos tipos de ejemplo que están en la documentación